# Is there a way to call a Return for a parent function from a child function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, return

I am having a really peculiar case. I want to `return` some data - data that is downloaded via ajax. So far async & sync modes don't get the data in time to the `return`. Is it possible I could either call `return` from a child function for the parent function or could a timeOut solve the issue? I can't think of another way of doing this, but the data must be returned.

Comment: return is *NOT* a function! Though perhaps raising an exception could do what you want?

Comment: Is there a certain way that an exception could return an array just like `return`?

Comment: Perhaps it would have been appropriate to tell in your function that you are using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to return value to parent function from nested anonymous function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455746/how-to-return-value-to-parent-function-from-nested-anonymous-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.

In asynchronous requests, the function has to return before the result is available. To work around this, a callback pattern is used - when calling such a function, you don't expect a return, but rather provide it with a callback - a function to be called once the result is available.

Here's a simple example:

```
var someValue;
fetchValueFrom('http://example.com/some/url/with/value', function(val) { 
  someValue = val; 
  doSomethingElseWith(someValue);
});
```

Here we create a function and pass it in as a second param to the `fetchValueFrom` call. Once the value is available this function will be called, and will set the variable and call another function to continue execution.

Answer (score 3):

You could provide a callback function:

```
function parentfunction(callback) {
    callback(getAjax());
}

function childfunction() {
    parentfunction(function(ajaxData) {
        //Do stuff with data
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just pass `false` as a third parameter to to `XMLHttpRequest.open`. It means "run this query synchronously".

[See the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#open()) for yourself.

Comment: I'd love if  `$.ajaxSetup({
  async:false
 })` would work for me, it'd solve all my problems but my code seems to ignore it?

Comment: "Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience."