# how to return value to parent function from nested anonymous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, anonymous-function

I have a javascript function which should return a geocoding for a string:

```
    function codeAddress(address) {
    var result = (new google.maps.Geocoder()).geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        return String(results[0].geometry.location.Ya)+','+String(results[0].geometry.location.Za)
      } else {
        return status;
      }
    });
    console.log(result);
    return result
}
```

However it returns "undefined". I understand the bug here,i.e, since javascript is asynchronous, its returning from the function `codeAddress` even before `function(results, status)` gets fully executed. But I need to know whats the solution here and the best practice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to call a Return for a parent function from a child function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338649/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-return-for-a-parent-function-from-a-child-function-in-j)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it's asynchronous, you should pass a callback which handles the function:

```
function codeAddress(address, callback) {
    (new google.maps.Geocoder()).geocode({
        'address' : address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            callback(String(results[0].geometry.location.Ya) + ','
                    + String(results[0].geometry.location.Za))
        } else {
            callback(status);
        }
    });
}

codeAddress("test", function(result) {
    // do stuff with result
});
```

If you're using jQuery, you could also use deferred:

```
function codeAddress(address, callback) {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();

    (new google.maps.Geocoder()).geocode({
        'address' : address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             // trigger success
            dfd.resolve(String(results[0].geometry.location.Ya) + ','
                    + String(results[0].geometry.location.Za));
        } else {
            // trigger failure
            dfd.reject(status); 
        }
    });

    return dfd;
}

codeAddress("some address").then(
    // success
    function(result) {
        // do stuff with result
    },
    // failure
    function(statusCode) {
        // handle failure
    }
);
```